# SQL COUNT the number of records on a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I trying to create a SQL query/stored procedure to count the number of applications in-progress on a certain day for a certain team.

Where I am having trouble is the following scenario: when the application is transferred to another user, the count for the day should not double count (a count for each team on the day of transfer) and should go to the transferred user.

My Tables

```
**Users**
Id  || Name   || TeamId
---------------------------------
 1     User 1     1
 2     User 2     2

**Application**
Id  || Name
------------- 
1      Application1

**ApplicationUser**
Id  || ApplicationId  || UserId || AssignedDate || UnassignedDate
----------------------------------------------------------
1           1               1        2018-03-01       2018-03-02
2           1               2        2018-03-02       2018-03-03
```

so in the Stored Procedure I am sending a date in as a parameter and the result i want to return is the following.

```
Date         || Team 1 || Team 2 || Total
-------------------------------------------
2018-03-02       0          1         1
```

so if I put all results together they would look like this.

```
Date         || Team 1 || Team 2 || Total
-------------------------------------------
2018-02-28       0          0         0 
2018-03-01       1          0         1 
2018-03-02       0          1         1
2018-03-03       0          1         1
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There are many things going on here. What part(s) of this do you need help with? You need a tally table or some way to get all the dates because they are not in your data. You also need a crosstab or a pivot.

Comment: There's some inconsistency: in your desired result, Team1 has 1 user only on first of march, since the user was unassigned on the following day, but for Team2 it's different, user was unassigned on third of march, but in your final displayed it's still 1 one on that day.

Comment: you don't have an entry for 2018-02-28. but in output 2018-02-28 is available. is this correct scenario.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your answers.

I have been trying this myself as well and I seem to have found the answer to my question.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME 
SELECT @DATE = '20180301'

SELECT ApplicationId, Max(UnassignedDate) as UnassignedDate
INTO #TempApplicationUsers 
FROM ApplicationUsers
WHERE @DATE > DAteAdd(Day, -1, AssignedDate) and (@DATE < UnassignedDate OR 
UnassignedDate is NULL)
Group BY ApplicationId

SELECT * From  #TempApplicationUsers

SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) FROM ApplicationUsers, #TempApplicationUsers 
WHERE ApplicationUsers.ApplicationId = #TempApplicationUsers.ApplicationId 
and ISNULL(ApplicationUsers.UnassignedDate, 0) = 
ISNULL(#TempApplicationUsers.UnassignedDate, 0)
GROUP BY UserId
DROP TABLE #TempApplicationUsers
```

This returns the count for each user on that day and from this I can get the count for each team by the TeamId in the users table.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## DDL:

Here I define table variables and insert data you provided:

```
declare @users table (id int, name varchar(10), teamid int)
insert into @users values (1, 'user1', 1),(2, 'user2',2)
declare @application table (id int, name varchar(15))
insert into @application values (1, 'application1')
declare @applicationuser table (id int, applicationid int, userid int, assigneddate date, unassigneddate date)
insert into @applicationuser values (1,1,1,'2018-03-01','2018-03-02'),(2,1,2,'2018-03-02','2018-03-03')
```

## Query:

```
--here I sum values for each team using cumulative sum
select [date],
       sum(team1) over (order by [date] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [team1],
       sum(team2) over (order by [date] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [team2],
       sum(total) over (order by [date] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [total]
from (
    --here I am pivoting inner query, replacing NULL values using COALESCE
    select [date],
           coalesce(max(case when teamid = 1 then value end), 0) [team1],
           coalesce(max(case when teamid = 2 then value end), 0) [team2],
           coalesce(max(case when teamid = 1 then value end), 0) + coalesce(max(case when teamid = 2 then value end), 0) [total]
    from (
        --here I join assigned and unassigned dates with team ids
        select [AU].assigneddate [date], [U].teamid, 1 [value] from @applicationuser [AU] 
        join @users [U] on [AU].userid = [U].id

        union all

        select [AU].unassigneddate, [U].teamid, -1 from @applicationuser [AU] 
        join @users [U] on [AU].userid = [U].id
    ) a 
    group by [date]
) a
```

In order to understand this better is to try every query separatly, i.e. execute most inner query first, then wrap it with outer query and see the results. This way you'll know what's happening at each step.

Comment: Don't suppose you want to explain what you are doing here?  Code only answers are not very helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of queries are best dealt with using a dates table.  If you don't have one in your database already I strongly suggest you get one.

In the meanwhile, you can create a dates table on the fly using either an inline table valued function or a derived table within your query (Note I have added an additional open application):

```
-- Declare test data
declare @users table (id int, name varchar(10), teamid int);
declare @application table (id int, name varchar(15));
declare @applicationuser table (id int, applicationid int, userid int, assigneddate date, unassigneddate date);

insert into @users values (1, 'user1', 1),(2, 'user2',2);
insert into @application values (1, 'application1'),(2, 'application1');
insert into @applicationuser values (1,1,1,'2018-03-01','2018-03-02'),(2,1,2,'2018-03-02','2018-03-03'),(2,2,2,'2018-03-02','2018-03-05');


-- Find the maximum date range possible to create a dates table that covers all possible application periods
declare @MinDate date = (select min(AssignedDate) from @applicationuser);
declare @MaxDate date = (select max(UnassignedDate) from @applicationuser);

            -- This is a derived table that simply returns 10 rows
with t(t) as(select * from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(t))
            -- This then CROSS JOINs the 10 rows to create 10*10*10*10*10 = 100,000 rows
            -- Then uses the ROW_NUMBER function to add a number of days to the @MinDate value, to get a table of incrementing dates
    ,d(d) as(select top(datediff(day,@MinDate,@MaxDate)+1) dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@MinDate) from t,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5)
select d.d                            -- Output is a row per date and teamid where there was an open application.
      ,u.teamid                       -- When grouped together this gives you a COUNT of open applications by teamid
      ,count(1) as OpenApplications
from d
    join @ApplicationUser as au
        on d.d between au.assigneddate and au.unassigneddate
    join @users as u
        on au.userid = u.id
group by d.d
      ,u.teamid
order by d.d
        ,u.teamid
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------+------------------+
|     d      | teamid | OpenApplications |
+------------+--------+------------------+
| 2018-03-01 |      1 |                1 |
| 2018-03-02 |      1 |                1 |
| 2018-03-02 |      2 |                2 |
| 2018-03-03 |      2 |                2 |
| 2018-03-04 |      2 |                1 |
| 2018-03-05 |      2 |                1 |
+------------+--------+------------------+
```

---

I have purposefully not `pivot`ed your data to match your desired output as this is almost always a bad idea.  As your number of teams change, your number and names of columns outputted will change, which will require constant maintenance.  Instead, you should just output a normal set of data and leave the `pivot`ing to the presentation layer once it eventually gets there.

Answer (score 0):

is this use full:

```
    DECLARE @users TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(10), teamid INT)
    INSERT INTO @users VALUES (1, 'user1', 1),(2, 'user2',2)
    DECLARE @application TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(15))
    INSERT INTO @application VALUES (1, 'application1')
    DECLARE @applicationuser TABLE (id INT, applicationid INT, userid INT, assigneddate DATE, unassigneddate DATE)
    INSERT INTO @applicationuser VALUES (1,1,1,'2018-03-01','2018-03-02'),(2,1,2,'2018-03-02','2018-03-03')


    DECLARE @assignment TABLE([date] DATE,teamid INT,[value] INT)

    INSERT INTO @assignment
    SELECT [AU].assigneddate [date], [U].teamid, 1 [value]
    FROM @applicationuser [AU] 
    JOIN @users [U] ON [AU].userid = [U].id

    INSERT INTO @assignment
    SELECT [AU].unassigneddate, [U].teamid, 
        CASE WHEN  LEAD(AssignedDate) OVER(ORDER BY [AU].id)=unassigneddate 
            THEN -1
        ELSE 
            1
        END         
    FROM @applicationuser [AU] 
    JOIN @users [U] ON [AU].userid = [U].id


    SELECT b.[date],
        CASE WHEN t1.teamid=1 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 
            0 
        END AS Team1,
        CASE WHEN t1.teamid=2 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 
            0 
        END AS Team2,
        total
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [date],  MAX([value]) AS Total
        FROM @assignment
        group by [date]
    )b
    INNER JOIN @assignment t1 ON b.Total=t1.Value AND b.[date]=t1.[date]
    ORDER BY b.[date]
```